# how to connect a signal to a nonstatic method of a static member

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to connect somehow to a nonstatic method of a static member if this member is not a `QObject`? I know about a workaround using a lambda, but I am curious if there another way which I do not know about.

```
class Value { // not a QObject!
  void setValue(int);
}

class Globals {
  static Value value; // is static member!
}

class Sender : public QObject {
signals:
  void valueChanged(int);
}

Sender *sender;
// the following does not work because Value is not a QObject
connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged, &Globals::value, &Value::setValue);
// the following is a naive attempt, it is not a correct C++
connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged, &Globals::value.setValue);
// this works but is ugly
connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged, [](int val) { Globals::value.setValue(val); });
// is there another way???
```

Comment: it is possible with boost signals, which can be used in a qt application.

Comment: IMHO, C++ lambdas are perfect for such adapters. (I'm happy that Qt supports this since Qt5. I remember with horror the `sigc::bind()` and `sigc::hide()` we used in gtkmm prior C++11.) Do you think there could be anything better?

Comment: `Q_OBJECT` macro is needed by QT's moc, why you don't want `Value` to be a `QObject` in the first place?

Comment: @codekaizer Actually my first problem with `QObject` was that my actual `Value` class (in my real code, not in this simple example) is a templated class and `Q_OBJECT` cannot be combined with templates. On the other hand, as I just found, connecting to `QObject` methods does not require `Q_OBJECT` macro, but only inheriting from `QObject`. The first `connect` form in my example would work then. Therefore I am considering turning my `Value` into `QObject`. Seems I got trapped by X-Y problem. My problem was with templates and `QObject` rather than connecting to static member methods. :)

Comment: you have to create a functor, either with bind, the way you did it, or the thousands other ways to create functor in c++11. there is no magic.

Comment: Inheriting from `QObject` may add a certain amount of administrative "load" to `class Value`. I would ask me whether this is worth the fact that you do not anymore need a lambda (or one of the other thousand ways to create a functor in C++11) to register a signal handler. ;-)